# Rails 3 Jquery Star Rating plugin problem submitting

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use Rails 3 and JQuery Star Rate plugin http://orkans-tmp.22web.net/star_rating/index.html#main-menu=1&demo-tabs=1 . The problem is that the hidden field generated by the plugin is not being submitted in the rails form

```
<%= form_for(@wine) do |f| %>
 <h3 class="h3wine"></h3>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name , :class => "left"%>
  <label class="right"><%= f.text_field :name %> </label><br />
 </div>
 <div class="note_fields">
   <h2 style="margin-left: 20%;">Note</h2>
    <% f.fields_for :notes do |builder| %>
   <%= render 'note_fields', :f => builder %>
<% end %>   
  </div>

 <span>
   <%= f.submit %>
 </span>
<% end %>
```

Then the partial note_fields.html.erb is like

```
<script>

  $("#stars-wrapper1").stars();
 </script>
 <p>
<div class="field">
    Rating: <span id="stars-cap"></span>
        <div id="stars-wrapper1">
            <br>
            <% [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' ].each do |rates| %>
                <%= f.radio_button :rating, rates%>
            <% end %>
        </div>                
    </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :text, :class => "left" %>
    <label class="right"><%= f.text_area :text,:size => "60x12" %></label><br />
  </div>
</p>
```

So everything is ok, related to displaying the stars and show the value of "rating" from database. The problem is when submitting in the log file the field rating doesn't come.

The generated hiiden field is like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="5" name="wine[notes_attributes][0][rating]" disabled="">
```

Which get well updated once the stars are changed.

In the log this what shows:

```
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Update Wine", "wine"=>{"name"=>"Borba", "notes_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"text"=>"borbocas", "id"=>"6666"}}}, "authenticity_token"=>"/FsKTnSm2eAvPQiXie
```

Oh. If it helps , If I don't use the plugin and mantain the radio_buttons it work ok.

Thanks for the help :)

**Update** - Thanks to all of you -

Exactly @Kris :) I realizes that yesterday night .. but I was too tired to post the answer . Thanks a lot :)

So I've bind a javascript function to the submit event form. So when the form is submitted the attribute disabled is remove. 
Because every time you click on the stars this hidden field is updated as so the disabled field is inserted

```
 <script>
 $("form").submit(function () { 
     $("input[name^=\"wine[notes_attributes][0][rating]\"]").removeAttr("disabled");}‌​);
 $("#stars-wrapper1").stars(); 
 </script>
Thanks guys :)
```

Comment: could be handy: http://teachmetocode.com/screencasts/building-a-star-rating-system-in-ruby-on-rails-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

Check your jquery version, star rating supports jquery up to 1.5.2.
Newer jquery versions does fall into this bug.

Comment: going back to 1.5.2 fixed the disabled bug for me (i didn't need to hack anything)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the generated hidden field has a disabled attribute and disabled fields are not valid for submission.

Read this:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12

I'm having this issue myself using jQuery UI Stars v3.0.1, jQuery 1.6.1 and still trying to figure out a solution to this.

**UPDATE:**

OK, I've came up with a solution. It's a hack, but it fixes the issue.

Basically I'm using jQuery to go through the hidden inputs and remove the disabled attribute:

```
$("input[type=hidden]").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: Exactly :) I realizes that yesterday night .. but I was too tired to post the answer . Thanks a lot :)
So I've bind a javascript function to the submit event form. So when the form is submitted the attribute disabled is remove. Because every time you click on the stars this hidden field is updated as so the disabled field is inserted  

`$("form").submit(function () { $("input[name^=\"wine[notes_attributes][0][rating]\"]").removeAttr("disabled");});
$("#stars-wrapper1").stars();
function () {
$("input[name^=\"wine[notes_attributes][0][rating]\"]").removeAttr("disabled");}`
Thanks guys :)

Comment: @diogui, you should probably edit your question with your answer for other people to benefit from in future.

Comment: @diogui, I'd probably just remove disabled attribute from all hidden input fields, since disabled attribute will not work with hidden inputs.

Answer (score 0):

looks like that attribute should be getting posted.

On your model do you need something like this?

attr_accessible :rating

Or are you limiting what is accessible in any way?

Comment: Hi Ryan,
Thanks for you quick answer.
in my Wine model I have
   `class Wine < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name,  :presence => true
  has_many :notes ,:dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :user
  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :notes
 end`
and in Note.rb I have 

    `class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :wine
      belongs_to :user
    end`

I've tried to put attr_accessible :rating on my Note model but no luck ...

Comment: Hmm, not quite sure. My guess is it has to do with the nesting. I'm not a Rails expert, but I think wine[notes_attributes][0][rating] should look like this? like wine[notes_attributes][rating]  .. if rating is directly on note.  I think.  You could manually write out the hidden field f.hidden_field and write it out yourself when posting it. Just to see if you can get the variables coming through right in your hash you can see in your log.

Comment: Thanks. I know that wine[notes_attributes][0][rating] is the way it should be because before I had it in radio buttons and it worked.But I'll try what you are saying. Oh and rails generates a hidden field for the nested object (note in this case) with the id of the object, and that works. So it doesn't seem to be a problem the hidden fields with the nested objects :)

Comment: Ok it's interesting . I have created a ` <%= f.hidden_field :rating %>` and it submits the data on that field, but ofcourse is not updated when the stars are changed. So the problem seem to be the hidden field generated by the jquery plugin ... strange.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running JQuery 1.7.2 and JQuery UI Stars 3.0.1.

It seems the regression is related to how JQuery handles boolean attributes now...

Here are my changes:

`73: o.disabled = o.disabled || (o.isSelect ? $(self.$selec).is(':disabled') : $(this).is(':disabled'));`

and

`155: self.$value.attr({disabled: o.disabled, value: o.value});`